# @ModelAttribute having Collection property - values get added to the collection, not replaced?

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc

I have this class:

The PreApprovalRequest class has a property `headings` that gets populated automatically in the controller (see code of Controller lower on the page).

```
public class PreApprovalRequest {
    private Long id;
    private String Description;
    private Collection<Headings> headings; //this property!
}
```

And the controller:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes({"preApprovalRequest", "productRecommendations"})
public class RequestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/submit",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitResults(@ModelAttribute(value = "preApprovalRequest") @Valid PreApprovalRequest preApprovalRequest, BindingResult errors) {
        //HERE: It looks like if I have some headings in the preApprovalRequest object already, the call of this method will not delete those, but will append to the existing list.
        //save object in DB.
        return "dashboard";
    }
}
```

Any idea how to make Spring replace collection objects rather than adding to it?

Comment: This is the expected behavior with SessionAttributes holding the same `preApprovalRequest` variable. If you don't want a fresh `headings` to be created from what you are submitting, simply remove it from `SessionAttributes`

Comment: I do want a fresh headings every time. That's the problem, I don't get it. Spring seems to just add to the list of headers instead of removing the old ones and keeping only the new ones. I have no idea why one would even want that, can't understand why they implemented it like that in Spring?!

Answer (score 0):

How I understood your question is, you cann't replace your `headings` collections to have a new collections of `Headings`. Can't you do that in the following way?

```
preApprovalRequest.setHeadings(new ArrayList<Headings>());
preApprovalRequest.getHeadings().add(heading1);
```

Comment: Yes, you understood it correctly. I want Spring to remove the old list and put the new list in the object. No, that won't work as the setting of the headings is done automatically by Spring, so by the time I get to do anything like what you proposed, Spring have already added the new headings to the old list. Thus I won't know which are the new headings and which the old ones ...

Answer (score 0):

Does it happen even if it's the first time you submit your form? If not, try cleaning your cache after you're done with all actions in your controller.

Add the SessionStatus in your method and call "setComplete()" to clean the attributes. Thus, the second time you start your process, your cache will be empty and you will have to use a new preApprovalRequest

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submit",  method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitResults(@ModelAttribute(value = "preApprovalRequest") @Valid PreApprovalRequest preApprovalRequest, BindingResult errors, SessionStatus status) {
    /HERE: It looks like if I have some headings in the preApprovalRequest object already, the call of this method will not delete those, but will append to the existing list.
    //save object in DB.

    status.setComplete();
    return "dashboard";
}
```

Comment: Yes, it happens all the time. I can't complete the session as when I set the headers, the 'wizard' is not yet done. I do that once the PreApprovalRequest gets saved in DB, one wizard step later.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is dynamic shrinking /expanding kind of List, then collection has to be lazy.Apache commons collection provides a Lazy List class which does that.You can get the apache commons collection from : http://commons.apache.org/collections/

So your controller model can be re written as:

```
public class PreApprovalRequest {
    private Long id;
    private String Description;
    private List headings;

    public PreApprovalRequest()
    {
        headings=LazyList.decorate(
           new ArrayList(),
           FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(Header.class));
    }

}
```

Idea behind binding data to list is, keeping track of the list item index with in the html elements name attribute:

```
<c:forEach item="${modelAttr.list}" varStatus="listItem">

<form:input type="text" path="list[${listItem.index}]" />

</c:forEach>
```

Comment: thanks, but no, that's not what I'm looking for. I only want Spring not to add new headings to the list I already have in the session object, but replace the old headings with the newly submitted ones.